# Firestore lite not working but Firestore is. "Error: Service firestore/lite is not available" after webpack compilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, webpack

## Problem

When i compile webpack and run dist/index.js (command: `node dist/index.js`), the error message appears:

```
Error: Service firestore/lite is not available
    at e.getImmediate (D:\Projects\2023\firebase-test\dist\index.js:2:14249)
    at sr (D:\Projects\2023\firebase-test\dist\index.js:2:89298)
    at 492 (D:\Projects\2023\firebase-test\dist\index.js:2:148319)
    at n (D:\Projects\2023\firebase-test\dist\index.js:2:162316)
    at D:\Projects\2023\firebase-test\dist\index.js:2:162828
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\2023\firebase-test\dist\index.js:2:162836)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
```

However, the code works ok when I import firebase/firestore instead of firebase/firestore/lite

## These are my files

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^10.3.1"
  }
}
```

index.ts

```js
import {doc, getDoc, getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
...
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
export async function getDocFromFirestore(path: string, id: string) {
    // @ts-ignore
    const ref = doc(firestore, path, id);
    return (await getDoc(ref)).data();
}

getDocFromFirestore('lessons', 'id').then(value => {
    console.log(value)
})
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: {
            import: './index.ts',
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', 'scss'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    watch: true,
    optimization: {
        usedExports: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: 'file-loader', options: {name: '[name].css'}},
                    {loader: 'extract-loader'},
                    {loader: 'css-loader'},
                    {loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {postcssOptions: {plugins: [autoprefixer()]}}},
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {/* Prefer Dart Sass*/
                            implementation: require('sass'), /* See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804*/
                            webpackImporter: false,
                            sassOptions: {includePaths: ['./node_modules']},
                        },
                    }],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
};
```